# RecyclerView Height depends on item

Tags: android, height, android-recyclerview

I tried maximum of Stack Overflow answers.Nothing is worked in my case. Here I have a RecyclerView. I need to increase the recyclerview height depends on the items(Review of a products).But whatever I do, it is fixed in its height that I have given in xml.Please help me.

[image]

My XML Code for this View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Layout_mw"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerLinear"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/reviewList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there It's normal that the height is fixed because you fixed it.
If you want it to be dynamic according to the its content then you should proceed like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Layout_mw"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerLinear"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/reviewList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I replace the fixed height  ***200dp*** with ***wrap_content***
(of course if you set height by code you need to use ***wrap_content*** in your code too).
Hope that helps.